# How to add a PHP module to Apache in Redhat/Centos?

Tags: php, apache, centos

I am using Apache on Redhat/Centos, there are no PHP modules. Can anyone tell me where can I find a PHP module with .SO extension file? In www.php.net there are no .SO extension files.

Comment: FYI PHP has *extensions* not *modules*

Comment: Have you searched for "Redhat install PHP module" on the web? I should think there are plenty of resources out there for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, PHP `.so` extensions are packaged in separate packages in a system. For example, you can get the mcrypt.so extension on RedHat/CentOS by:

```
sudo yum install php-mcrypt
```

then, you could find it at `/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so`. Also you could find the associated `/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini`, which will get loaded by php when you restart Apache, or php-fpm.

Answer (score 1):

PHP extensions (not modules) are either compiled in when you install php via flags with the ./configure command (i.e. --with-curl ... etc) Or by telling your php.ini file where the .so file is (which will be available when you restart apache and therefore PHP)

If you are planning on using a dynamic extension, which are the .so files, then you need to compile or grab a pre compiled version for your distro, and include it in your php.ini file. You can find out your php.ini file location via the command line like so:

php -i |grep 'php.ini'

Answer (score 0):

A note for those using PHP7.1 for RH7 from the Webtatic repository
(http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm)

The packages needed for PHP7.1 are:

`sudo yum install php71w-fpm php71w-opcache php71w-common php71w-process php71w-pdo php71w-gd libmcrypt php71w-mcrypt php71w-mbstring mod_php71w`

particularly the php module for apache is called:
**mod_php71w**